# Issue with editing input via websockets by two users

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I was trying to implement feature of working with same input field with two users using socket.io
Idea looks like this:

1. User enters data
2. Data goes to backend
3. Backend broadcast data across all connected clients

But when I tried to enter a single char - whole input value somehow was set to "" (literally nothing)
Maybe I should handle data flow in another way ?

Client code to send data to backend and acquire it on response:

```
    $('input').keydown(function(){
       socket.emit('chat message', $('input').val());
       console.log($('input').val());
       return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('input').val(msg);
    });
```

Backend code which only used to broadcast data across all conected clients:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

GitHub repo link: https://github.com/eko24/websocket-input

Comment: keydown fires before the value changes

Comment: Relevant code MUST be pasted into your question, NOT only available in an external link.  That is a stack overflow policy.

Comment: @jfriend00, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `<input>` tag has not yet been changed when the `keydown` event is fired so you're not seeing the effect of the key that was just pressed.

Instead, you can use the "input" event which signifies when the `<input>` value has been changed by the user:

```js
$("input").on("input", function(e) {
    log($("input").val());
});

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```